# Logical mistake in a proof of Dirichlet's test

Tags: proof-writing, improper-integrals, examples-counterexamples, riemann-integration

While writing a proof of Dirichlet's Test, [ in which, a required condition is that $\displaystyle{\int_a^B\phi(x)dx}$ is bounded $\forall B>a]$, I made a logical mistake, which I noticed upon revision. The mistake is as follows:

Let $\displaystyle{\vert\int_a^B\phi(x)dx \vert}\leq M, \ [ \ \forall B>a] \implies \displaystyle{\vert\int_{x_1}^\xi\phi(x)dx \vert} \leq M$
, $[x_1,\xi] \subset (a,B)$.

To support the fact that I was mistaken, I try to construct a function $\phi(x)$, such that :

$\phi(x)=-1$, when $x \in [1,2]$

$=2$, when $x\in [2,3]$

$=1/x^2$ in $(3, B]$

Clearly, $\displaystyle{ \vert \int_1^B\phi(x)dx \vert}\leq1$, but $\displaystyle{ \vert \int_2^3\phi(x)dx \vert}=2\nleq1$.

Is this example valid enough to show that I was mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counterexample does not show that for all $B >1$

$$\left|\int_1^B f(x) \, dx \right| \leqslant 1$$

If $B > 3$, then we have

$$\begin{align}\left|\int_1^B f(x) \, dx \right| &= \left|\int_1^2 (-1) \, dx +  \int_2^3 (2) \, dx + \int_3^B \frac{dx}{x^2} \right| \\ &= -1 + 2 + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{B} \\ &= \frac{4}{3} - \frac{1}{B} \\ &> \frac{4}{3} - \frac{1}{3} \\ &= 1\end{align}$$

You can easily find other constant values $f(x) = C$ on $[1,2]$  where this works. Using $C = -\frac{3}{2}$, for example, we have

$$-\frac{3}{2} + 2 + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{B} = \frac{5}{6} - \frac{1}{B} < \frac{5}{6} < 1$$

Of course to prove the Dirichlet's test where it is given that $\left|\int_a^B f(x) \, dx\right|< M$ is uniformly bounded for all $B > a$ it is not necessary to have $\left|\int_{x_1}^\xi f(x) \, dx\right|< M$ for any $[x_1,\xi] \subset [a,B]$.

All that will matter is that we have the bound

$$\left|\int_{x_1}^\xi f(x) \, dx\right| = \left|\int_{a}^\xi f(x) \, dx - \int_{a}^{x_1} f(x) \, dx \right| \leqslant \left|\int_{a}^\xi f(x) \, dx \right| +\left|\int_{a}^{x_1} f(x) \, dx \right| \leqslant M+M = 2M $$

Note that $\left|\int_{a}^\xi f(x) \, dx \right|, \,\,\left|\int_{a}^{x_1} f(x) \, dx \right| \leqslant M$ when $\xi > a$.

Comment: Can you modify the function so that my argument holds?

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas: I already did so.  Let $f(x) = -3/2$ on $[1,2]$, $f(x) = 2$ on $[2,3]$ and $f(x) = 1/x^2$ on $(3,\infty)$.

Comment: Replace $1/x^2$ by $3/x^2$ !?

Comment: Read what I wrote after "Using $C = -3/2$, ..."

Comment: I am sorry, I missed that line.

Comment: With that constant we still have $\int_2^3 f(x) dx = 2> 1$ but $\int_1^B f(x) \, dx < 1$.

Comment: Your example is perfect and remains bounded within any $[1,B]$. Now, can you check mine?

Comment: Please read my answer fully.  Before that I proved that your example did not work. You get $\int_1^B f = -1 + 2 + 1/3 - 1/B$ which is greater than $1$ for all $B > 3$.

Comment: Again please read the answer fully.

Comment: Now, with $3/x^2$, we have $-1+2+3(1/3-1/B) \leq 1$ for any $B≥3$

Comment: I did read your complete answer (but missed your modifications), and realized that my function is going to fail. Then I tried to replace $1/x^2$ by $3/x^2$ to make it work.

Comment: So $-1 + 2 +3(1/3 - 1/B) = -1 + 2 + 1 - 3/B = 2 - 3/B$. If $B > 3$ then $3/B < 1$ and $-3/B > -1$ and $2 - 3/B > 1$. So your modification also does not work.

Comment: I have now proved that your original counterexample does not work, gave you one that does work and showed your modified example in comments does not work.  I also explained why none of this matters in the proof of the Dirichlet test.

Comment: Now try $-3/x^2$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88491/discussion-between-subhasis-biswas-and-rrl).

Comment: Sir, I know I am making some stupid mistakes, but I want to come up with my own example and I need a helping hand.